# NodeJS app with ebextensions not deployed to Beanstalk via Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, github, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, filebeat, ebextensions

I have a sample Hello World app in NodeJS which's sourcecode in GitHub. The sourcecode is pushed to the AWS Beanstalk environment whenever a new commit happens via a Jenkins job. The sourcecode consists of **an .ebextensions folder an inside that, there is a filebeat.config file which is supposed to install and configure FileBeat inside the Beanstalk environment**.

The Jenkins is hosted in a t2.micro EC2 instance. The Beanstalk environment and the Jenkins server are inside the same VPC. The Jenkins job runs and the outcome is shown as SUCCESS. However, when I check the AWS Beanstalk dashboard, although I can see the latest version on the top, I don't see it in the Deployed state. (The **Deployed to** in the row of that application version is empty).
I checked the console output for the Jenkins job, and there's a warning which says :

> WARNING: Environment (environmentId='e-ke2unpe3sm')
> doesn't have matching versionLabels (expected:
> jenkins-hw-elk-node-1-5; found: Sample Application)

I am not sure if this is an issue with the Beanstalk configuration or because of an error in .ebextensions files.
I have attached a screenshot of the *filebeat.config* file inside the folder *.ebextensions*

[image]